# Is creating separate classes for simple data structures are overkill in Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, json, web-services

I am creating simple web-service client in Objective-C and found that creating separate class for each kind of web-service's response could be overkill. Perhaps this because Objective-C has two files - H&M.

Here is sample of responses from web-service:

```
{"name": "John", status: "OK"}
```

or

```
{"total": "5500", status: "OK"}
```

or more complex

```
{"location": {"x": "140", "y": "90", "z": "0"}, 
 "color": "red", status: "OK"}
```

I want to create separate class for each response, e.g. NameResponse, TotalResponse, LocationInfoResponse and subclass them from Response class.

I am sure in Java that would be quite compact to create some classes, but not sure about Objective-C.

**UPDATE 1**
One reason to use classes over NSDictionary is that code is more safe and better defined, e.g.:

I think

```
response.name
```

is better than

```
json valueForKey: "name"
```

Isn't it?

Please put how would you do in the answer and is a class per each response is overkill in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having your data model clearly specified is never overkill. And formal data types are the best kind of specification – they’re already implemented!

If the web service responses are transferred between layers of your application, use classes. If the scope of their use is small enough, a NSDictionary might be acceptable.

Comment: Having your data model clearly specified almost guarantees an incompatibility with future versions of the service.

Comment: @Seva Versioning and compatibility is a difficult issue dealing with which is probably outside the scope of what the OP is asking, and has to be dealt with when designing the service to begin with. What structures exactly a WS client will unmarshal a response into will neither make or break compatibility. (As opposed to *how* it will unmarshal it, how missing / extraneous values are handled, how exactly will the response be used further, etc.)

Comment: @Seva I'm also assuming that the OP is in control of the service and that it's only purpose is to feed this one client, a use case which requires less futureproofing than published web APIs designed for wide consumption.

Comment: Right. That's exactly why the OP is quite likely to NOT futureproof the protocol, and when the future suddenly happens... oops! "Simple" in the question text is something of a giveaway.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, "Simple", this is true and false. I am actually started with simple responses which has 1 or 2 properties, but there are more complex compound like the third response with location data.

Comment: The primary problem with using ObjC dictionaries to store JSON is the obtuse syntax required to both set and get data from them. A dynamic language like ObjC just begs for a more elegant handling of dynamic DDL's.

Answer (score 3):

For a name-value collection, a dictionary object might come in handy. If your ObjC work happens to be on an Apple platform, consider `NSDictionary`.

In fact, I'm surprised your JSON parser requires specific classes. JSON maps pretty cleanly on the Cocoa classes - you have your NSDictionary for objects, NSArray for arrays, NSString and NSNumber for scalars.

Comment: do you think that dealing with NSDictionary directly in dynamic way pulling all necessary properties from it is better and lighter than wrapping data into classes and then work with classes as first class objects, etc.?

Comment: No, I think it's more stable to the evolving schema. Also, allows for much simpler parser code.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C classes are not heavy, subclassing is not a performance issue. You could create an abstract class and put your base fields in there. Then subclass as necessary to add fields, inheriting as it makes sense along the way.

Depending on your needs, simply parsing the json into an NSArray/NSDictionary can work just fine. You can then use `valueForKeyPath:` to walk paths and get specific values out of your root collection. I find this solution elegant on complex collections that use heavy composition. Use `#define` or `const` to create the path keys so they are easy to change and you can get compile time validation of your keys.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForKeyPath: